How to add the same value in all rows when the column value is NULL
I have a table with data like below and would like to see the col4 and col5 values repeated for all the rows and do not need col2 and col3 values with Null.
create table #table1(
ID int,
State varchar(50),
Col2 varchar(10),
Col3 varchar(10),
Col4 varchar(10),
Col5 varchar(10)
)


insert into #table1 
select 1,'TX',Null,NUll,'EEE','1234'
UNION ALL
select 1,'TX','AAA' ,'3456',NULL,NULL            
UNION ALL
select 1,'TX','BNH' ,'3467',NULL,NULL  
UNION ALL
select 1,'TX','GFR' ,'1356',NULL,NULL  
UNION ALL
select 1,'TX','UPY' ,'2345',NULL,NULL 

If I do Max on columns, I get just one row as a result
select ID,State,
MAX(Col2) as Col2,
MAX(Col3) as Col3,
MAX(Col4) as Col4,
MAX(Col5) as Col5
from #table1
group by ID,State

Result:
ID  State   Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5
1   TX      UPY     3467    EEE     1234

final out put expected is:
ID  State  col2  col3   Col4   Col5
1   TX     AAA   3456   EEE   1234
1   TX     BNH   3467   EEE   1234
1   TX     GFR   1356   EEE   1234
1   TX     UPY   2345   EEE   1234

Can anyone please help me ?

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

What version of SQL Server?

Additional examples might be useful here too as MAX would work here.

thank yu guys. I have edited my question . MAX wont work here. I am using SQL server 2020

There is no SQL Server 2020. There were releases in 2019 and 2022, but not in 2020.

The column name ID implies it's unique. Please use a different name for a non-unique column.

This data and model are not relational. Why are there 4 rows in the result set and not five? Where did the fifth one go?

where did the 5th row go?

I think, row (1,'TX',Null,NUll,'EEE','1234') should be excluded from output.

IsNull Function will fulfill your requirements.
select id, state,col2,col3
  ,isnull(col4, (select max(col4) from #table1)) col4
  ,isnull(col5, (select max(col5) from #table1)) col5
from #table1
where col2 is not null and col3 is not null


Yes, it can be achieved by using the MAX aggregation function with the CASE statement to select the non-null values from col4 and col5. The CASE statement checks if the value is not null and, if so, returns the value.
Here is an example:
SELECT 
  ID,
  State,
  col2,
  col3,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Col4 IS NOT NULL THEN Col4 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS Col4,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Col5 IS NOT NULL THEN Col5 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS Col5
FROM 
  YourTable
WHERE 
  col2 IS NOT NULL AND col3 IS NOT NULL

I am using the ID, State, col2, and col3 columns, as well as the calculated col4 and col5 columns.
This is aggregating the data and excluding the null.

this will give me Col4 and col5 as null .

I am getting output like this:
ID  State  col2  col3   Col4   Col5
1   TX     AAA   3456   EEE    1234
1   TX     BNH   3467   EEE    1234
1   TX     GFR   1356   EEE    1234
1   TX     UPY   2345   EEE    1234

@VijayPanwar, you should user where ... after aggregation max(...)over(...) (https://dbfiddle.uk/oBj7zdbZ)

See your expected result, col2 and col3 return their own value instead of the max value of the column, so put them to group by claus.
select
  ID,
  State,
  Col2,
  Col3,
  MAX(Col4) as Col4, 
  MAX(Col5) as Col5
from #table1
group by ID,State
where col2 is not null and col3 is not null


See example
select *
from(
  SELECT ID, State,
    col2, col3,
    MAX(Col4) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS Col4,
    MAX(Col5) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS Col5
  FROM #Table1
)t
WHERE col2 IS NOT NULL AND col3 IS NOT NULL

